# Arduino Mega output at 2.5 V and how to pull down?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, gpio, pulldown

In my Arduino project I want to connect the output of an Arduino to an input of a second Arduino.

Unfortunately on trying I found that the second Arduino input was always-on. On further investigation I found that pin 51 output gives about 2.5 V from the time I power the first Arduino. All other pins are 0 or nearly 0.

I read through the forums and found that input pins need to be pulled down for stopping them from floating, but should it be required when connected to output of the first Arduino?

Should I use a pull-down resistor to the rogue output? If I add a 5 kΩ resistor grounded between this output and the input of the second Arduino, should it be ok?

Weirdly in the IDE this pin (51) variable name "L" shows up as green while others are black.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: If pin 51 is high and remains high after you power on the Arduino 2560, it's most likely broken or your code has an error.  I also don't understand what you are trying to do with those relays. The way you have them connected in your diagram isn't going to do anything. Could you please explain what you are trying to do with your circuit?

Comment: For readers interested in this topic: The same question has been asked at the Arduino.cc forums, and is active [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-output-floating/672653), so new information / answers / updates might be posted there. [Link updated after destination website changed.]

Comment: tibu.v - Hi, Your power connections are unclear (not shown on the schematic) and the power sequencing is also unclear. Please edit the question to add *much* more detail. One possible interpretation of your question, is that you are powering one Arduino but not the other one, despite them having signal pins connecting them. If you are doing that, you should explain why you believe it is a valid configuration.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an Arduino's input connected to another Arduino's input. The role of an input is to "measure" with as little influence as possible on what's being measured. In essence they are "measuring" each other's input potential:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frr9ZR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By trying to measure that node's potential using a multimeter, the "floating"  situation didn't change at all:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc0sPn.png)</sup>

The potential is still ambiguous, and if you want it to be unambiguous, then you have to impose some kind of influence. A large value resistor can gently coerce ("pull down") the potential to zero (or "pull up" to +5V):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP1wFJ.png)</sup>

If you still measure +2.5V at the node, then something is broken, or you've made a mistake in your wiring, such as failing to join the grounds of the two  Arduinos.

If everything's working, then your multimeter, and the two Arduinos will measure 0V, logic "low". Without R1, the readings you get from any of those three devices will probably appear random, and nothing meaningful can be inferred from those readings.

Eventually, presumably, one of the Arduino's will change its input to an output, since the goal is for it to send information to the the other Arduino. When that happens, the "sending" device will now have control of the node's potential, easily able to overpower the weak influence of R1.

Only one of the devices needs to be configured as an output, to remove any ambiguity in the node's potential. The 2.5V you measured is absolutely meaningless. It's probably some mean value of fluctuations caused by mains voltages nearby, or the Arduino's own clock signal, "leaking" in capacitively.

The question is "do I need a pull-somewhere" resistor? The answer is no, you don't, the situation you described isn't "bad" in any way. It's just that you can't expect any voltage readings that you (or the Arduinos) take to be meaningful in any way. So don't expect Arduino 2's "reading" of its input to be at all useful information, prior to Arduino 1 taking control of the node, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem can be solved by implementing certain changes.

- Make all the GND connections common. This includes shorting both Arduino GNDs. Your floating problem will reduce significantly.
- Your 2.5V reading always staying the same can imply that either that the pinMode is not set right or there is an internal short in the PCB or the circuit built.Check your perpherals connected to the board.
- If there are multiple perpherals connected to your arduino mega, the current draw is more than the threshold. So technically your signal acts abnormally by fluctuating the signal strength in the circuit.
- Rearrange your code initialization, functions, setup and loop statements, figure where the loop does not work according to your requirement.
- To prove a point, try giving output of your mega from other pin than just 51. Check if the problem still exists.

These are the things I can think of from the top of my head right now. Hope this helped.